# How to make a process run slower in linux?

Tags: linux, process

I would like to keep a process running for a long time (e.g., more than half an hour). My program is gpg. If I encrypt a 500MB file using gpg elgamal encryption, it takes around 1-2 minutes (compression is turned off). To increase the running time, I can only create a file with a few GB, which is not desirable. Is there any other way to make this gpg program run for longer time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe, by default, `gpg` takes its input from standard input and sends output to standard output.

So you could make it run *forever* with something like:

```
gpg --encrypt </dev/urandom >/dev/null
```

To use that for consuming CPU for an hour (for example), you could create a script like:

```
gpg --encrypt </dev/urandom >/dev/null &
pid=$!
sleep 3600
kill -9 ${pid}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I need. You save my day!

Comment: @danny, day saving is my specialty :-)

Answer (score 2):

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18869/slow-down-a-process-without-affecting-other-processes

CPULimit might do what you need without affecting other processes:

http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/cpu-usage-limiter-for-linux/

You start the program, then run cpulimit against the program name or PID, specifying what percentage you want it limited.  Note the percentage is of all cores; so if you have 4 cores, you could use 400%.

Comment: That is not what the OP is asking for.

Comment: No, but it's what the question in the title asks for, so google will send a lot of people here looking for that.

Comment: Oh!  I misunderstood what you were saying.  I mistook it for the `ulimit` command.  Indeed, what you suggest is a great idea!

Comment: Thank you for your answer...I already accept paxdiablo's answer since his answer really solves my problem by running the program forever and I saw his answer much earlier...I understand that yours is more general, thank you again!